# redirect directory to new address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hi i want redirect my directory to new address and remove .html ext from end

example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/viewdownload/11-e/652-elena-2010.html
redirect to
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/11-e/652-elena-2010
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/viewdownload/9-b/1281-birdsong-2012.html
redirect to
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/9-b/1281-birdsong-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mod_rewrite is installed, just use URL rewriting in your .htaccess files. You can use URL rewriting to redirect users as well as doing an internal transfer.

A good reference is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Note that if there is any custom logic to mapping your old URIs to your new ones you might want to rewrite the old URIs to a PHP script which then returns the needed file.